# React "Rock Paper Scissors" Game Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, random

I'm making a *Rock Paper Scissors* game. I have tested certain parts and they seem to work separately but not all together.

I don't know what to try but I've tried different ways to do the number generator.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        rockPaperScissorsComputer: ['rock','paper','scissors'],
        random: null
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick() {
    const min = 1;
    const max = 100;
    const random = min + (Math.random() * (max - min));
    this.setState({ random })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button value="Click me!" onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
            <h1> {this.state.rockPaperScissorsComputer[this.state.random]} </h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

It should display `rock`/`paper`/`scissors` every time I click the button but nothing is displayed.

Comment: You're generating a random number between 0 and 100, while your `rockPaperScissors` array has only 3 elements. You should generate generate a random number between 0 - 2, like so: `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)`

Comment: yes that worked. I should've seen that. Thank you!

Comment: I've submitted an answer with some additional suggestions to improve your code

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. You're generating a random number between 0 and 100, while your `rockPaperScissors` array has only 3 elements (you should use your array's `length`).
2. You're generating a random number that may be a decimal, but array indexes should be whole numbers (you should use `Math.floor`).
3. You're storing the `rockPaperScissors` in your state, although it never changes (only use the state for storing data that changes over time and affects the view).
4. Using a class component for this is an overkill (you can convert it to a functional component with hooks and greatly reduce your code).

To generate a random whole number between `min` & `max`, you can do:

```
const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
```

So your final code should look like this:

```
const RockPaperScissors = () => {
  const [pick, setPick] = useState(null);

  const handleOnClick = useCallback(() => {
    const pool = ['rock','paper','scissors'];
    setPick(pool[Math.floor(Math.random() * pool.length)]);
  }, [setPick]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button value="Click me!" onClick={handleOnClick}>Click me</button>
      <h1>{pick}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```